# Corrupt label; bad magic number

Tags: hard-drive, installation, corruption, solaris-10, sun

While trying to install Solaris 10 on a Sun Blade 2500 Silver, I got an error: OpenBoot indicates me a problem with the hard drive: "Corrupt label; bad magic number". Later, during the Solaris installation process, the hard drive is not detected.

What does it mean and how can it be solved?

Comment: Were you trying to do an upgrade installation?  If so, try doing a standard full (overwrite) installation.

Comment: It's an installation from scratch on an used workstation I bought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I just had to use the format command in the Solaris installation console. I then chose the disk (only one in my workstation, so it was an easy choice), and things went rolling.